# Fetching rules from rpart using caret package

Tags: classification

I'm looking to find a way where I can extract rules from my decision tree. I have 8 predictors and they are all categorical variables and the response variable has three outputs A B and C.

I've developed the model and can also create decision tree but I'm having trouble in understanding the tree and be able to extract rules from my model.

The 8 predictors I have can have values a, b, c, d, e.

To give you an example, I want to extract rules from my decision tree like this:

- Rule 1:

  ```
  Predictor 1 - a  
  Predictor 2 - b  
  Predictor 3 - c  
  Predictor 4 - b  
  Predictor 5 - a  
  Predictor 6 - d  
  Predictor 7 - e  
  Predictor 8 - a  

  Result: A
  ```
- Rule 2:

  ```
  Predictor 1 - a  
  Predictor 2 - b  
  Predictor 3 - d  
  Predictor 4 - b  
  Predictor 5 - a  
  Predictor 6 - d  
  Predictor 7 - b  
  Predictor 8 - a  

  Result: A
  ```
- Rule 3:

  ```
  Predictor 1 - a  
  Predictor 2 - b  
  Predictor 3 - d  
  Predictor 4 - a  
  Predictor 5 - a  
  Predictor 6 - a  
  Predictor 7 - b  
  Predictor 8 - a  

  Result: B
  ```

and so on and so forth.

Is there a way I have rules from my decision tree like I explained above?

Here is the result of my model:

- 124 samples
- 8 predictors
- 3 classes: 'A', 'B', 'C'

No pre-processing.
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times).
Summary of sample sizes: 112, 111, 111, 112, 110, 112, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

```
  cp           Accuracy   Kappa  
  0.00000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.06329114  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.12658228  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.18987342  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.25316456  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.31645570  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.37974684  1.0000000  1.0000000  
  0.44303797  0.7261846  0.5696935
```

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was cp = 0.3797468.
n= 124

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

```
1) root 124 79 A (0.3629032 0.2741935 0.3629032)    
  2) Activity4e< 0.5 45  0 A (1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000) *  
    3) Activity4e>=0.5 79 34 C (0.0000000 0.4303797 0.5696203)    
      6) Activity7c>=0.5 34  0 B (0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000) *  
      7) Activity7c< 0.5 45  0 C (0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000) *
```

[image: visualising my decision tree]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rpart.rules function if you have used rpart to build the original tree.

```
library(rpart)
fit<-rpart(Reliability~.,data=car.test.frame)
rpart.rules(fit)
```